# Instant Chat on Web Application Using Firebase Database JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, web

In my website I am creating a instant messaging service using Firebase data base. I have got the functionality of the chat working so users can send a message to the chat which will display in the display box.

The problem I'm having is, when a new chat is created and users begin a conversation, the messages appear in order of the conversation they're having as they should As seen below:

[image]

but when the page is refreshed and the messages are pulled from the database is displays as follows.

[image]

My db structure for the chat is as follows:

[image]

And my JS code is for the chat is:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
 var db = firebase.database();
 var currentProperty = localStorage.getItem("prop");
 
 db.ref('addresses/'+currentProperty+'/chat/group').on("child_added", function(data){
  //Set Local Variables
  var message = data.child("message").val();
  var date = data.child("date").val();
  var sender = data.child("uid").val();
  var time = data.child("time").val();
  var who;
  var getCurrentDate = new Date;
  day = getCurrentDate.getDate();
  month = getCurrentDate.getMonth() + 1;          
  year = getCurrentDate.getFullYear();
  var newDate = [day, month, year].join('/');
  var title = document.getElementById("chatTitle");
  db.ref('addresses/'+currentProperty+'/firstLine').once("value", function(snapshot){
   title.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-home' style='font-size:150%;margin-right:10px'></i>Group chat with all persons involved with " + capitalLetter(snapshot.val());
  });
  
  if(sender == user.uid){who = 'boxCurrent currentUser';}
  else
  {who = 'boxOther otherUser';}
  
  if(date == newDate){date = 'Today'}
  
  db.ref('users/'+sender+'/firstName').on('value', function(data){
   var name = data.val();
   if(who == 'boxCurrent currentUser'){
    var messageD = "<div id='userMessageDisplay' style='width:100%;text-align:end;'><span class='message-data-time'>"+time+",  "+date+"    </span><span id='userName'>"+name+"</span><div id='hello' class='"+who+"' style= height:100%;'>"+message+"</div></div>";
   $('#displayBox').append(messageD);
   }
   else{
    var messageD = "<div id='userMessageDisplay' style='width:100%;'><span class='message-name'>"+name+"</span><span class='message-data-time'>    "+time+",  "+date+"</span><div id='hello' class='"+who+"' style='width:70%; height:100%;'>"+message+"</div></div>";
   $('#displayBox').append(messageD);
   }
  });
 });
 
 db.ref('addresses/'+currentProperty+'/tenant').orderByKey().once("value", function(snapshot){
  snapshot.forEach(function(child){
    var key = child.key;
    console.log(key);
    db.ref('users/'+key+'/firstName').once("value", function(data){
     var first = data.val();
     var appendFirst = "<li style='padding: 5px 10px 0 10px; height:75px;'><i class='fas fa-user-circle' style='font-size:400%; float:left;color:#6a6c75;'></i><div class='about' style='height:100%;padding: 10px 0 0 70px;'><div id='append2"+key+"' class='profileName' style='color:#fff;'>"+first;
     $('#peopleList').append(appendFirst);

    });
    db.ref('users/'+key+'/lastName').once("value", function(data){
     var last = data.val();
     var appendLast = " "+last+"</div>"
     $('#append2'+key).append(appendLast);
    });
    db.ref('users/'+key+'/onlineStatus').once("value", function(data){
     var onlineStatus = data.val();
     console.log(onlineStatus);
     if(onlineStatus == 'Online'){
     var appendStatus = "<div class='status' style='color:#a8aac3;'><i class='fa fa-circle' online style='color:#86BB71; margin-right:10px;font-size:80%;border:1px solid #fff;border-radius:50%;'></i>Online</div></div></li>"
     $('#append2'+key).append(appendStatus);
     }
     else{
      appendStatus = "<div class='status' style='color:#a8aac3;'><i class='fa fa-circle offline' style='color:#E38968;margin-right:10px;font-size:80%;border:1px solid #fff;border-radius:50%;'></i>Offline</div></div></li>"
      $('#append2'+key).append(appendStatus);
     }
    });
  });
 });
 
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
 location = 'index.html'
  }
});

function sendMessage(){
 var theDiv = document.getElementById('displayBox');
 var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
 var currentProperty = localStorage.getItem("prop");
 var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
 //date
 var date = new Date;
 day = date.getDate();
 month = date.getMonth() + 1;          
 year = date.getFullYear();
 var newDate = [day, month, year].join('/');
 var db = firebase.database();
 //time
 hours = date.getHours(); // => 9
 mins = date.getMinutes(); // =>  30
 var time = [hours, mins].join(':');
 console.log(time);
 
 var messageDetails = {
  "uid": user.uid,
  "message": message,
  "date": newDate,
  "time": time
  }
  
 if(message == ''){
  document.getElementById("messageInput").style.border = '1px solid red';
 }
 else{
  db.ref('addresses/'+currentProperty+'/chat/group').push(messageDetails).then(function(){
   document.getElementById("messageInput").value = '';
   theDiv.scrollTop = '99999';
  });
 }
}
```

Apologies for the long post but does anyone know why when the page is refreshed, the messages are clustered buy the user who sent the message?

Also any solutions to resolved the problem will be extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend changing the way you store your message timestamps. I would store them as firebase timestamps like this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue

and then when you pull them, you want to use `orderByChild` and then `startAt` from the retrieve data information found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

This will then order the messages based on their timestamp instead of their keys.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have manage to store the timestamp in my database for each message by when you said to use startAt to pull the data from the database, what value would i start at?

Comment: Take a look here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-ordered-data unless you are specifically starting at a certain spot, I would just not use `startAt` since it automatically does ascending order.

Comment: i've changed my query to "db.ref('addresses/'+currentProperty+'/chat/group').orderByChild('timeStamp').startAt().on("child_added", function(data){" but it still doesn't order the messages by timeStamp in ascending order.